# Как запомнить последнюю отправленную команду пользователя в телеграмм боте?

Tags: c#, telegram-bot

Пишу бота на C# возникла такая проблема, нужно запомнить команду пользователя. Например, пользователь нажимает инлайн кнопку "промо-код", далее ему(пользователю) нужно получить ответ, что данный промокод верен или нет. В общем в Python библиотеке есть такой метод register_next_step_handler(), он позволяет построить цепочку ответов, а как это реализовать в C#? На данный момент все команды храню в БД

Comment: Как вариант, можно создать список List<T> в котором будут хранится все сообщения от пользователя.

Comment: У вас наверняка реализован if или swith внутри бота. Почему вы не можете внутри условия реализовать метод? Пользователь ввёл сообщение типа `"Промо: абвг_1234"`, на вашей стороне вызывается метод типа `string checkPromo(string promo)`. По результату выдать `botClient.SendTextMessageAsync("Есть_промо_или_нет")`?

Comment: @Денис Если пользователь вводит какую-то дичь, то бот должен ответить, что он не знает такой команды + также пользователь когда покупает товар должен ввести свой Id или же когда пользователь пополняет баланс он мог указать свою сумму

Comment: в моём случае это реализовано так (если коротко): https://dotnetfiddle.net/xbBTl8

Comment: Добавил в код проверку по словам. Пройдите по ссылке ещё раз.